# autocomplete in asp.net with jquery not working fine with text box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, autocomplete

Web FORM1 code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ESEPAK.WebForm1" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
         <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#txtName').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetDisplayData',
                            method: 'post',
                            contentType: 'application/json,charset=utf-8',
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                term: request.term
                            }),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {

                                response(data.d)
                            },
                            error: function (err) {

                                alert(err);
                            }


                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">  Student Name : <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

**WEBSERVICE1.ASMX** CODE

```
namespace ESEPAK
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetDisplayData( string term)
        {
            List<string> listStudentNames = new List<string>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString; 
            using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) 
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpGetProductNames ", con); 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(){


                    ParameterName = "@term",
                    Value = term 
                });
                con.Open();



                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                while (rdr.Read()) 
                { listStudentNames.Add(rdr["Name"].ToString());
                } 
            } return listStudentNames;



        }
    }
}t
```

i have a parameterized stored procedure named 'term' and
everything is fine project is running but auto complete text box is not working i have twenty nine thousand records of Name is this why the response in j query is taking time? and i have added nothing on WebForm1.aspx.cs page and in page load. can anyone tell me why it's not working??

Comment: any javascript error ?

Comment: @Sami no there's no error, i think there is too much data that takes time or there is any other problem which i am unable to find

Comment: I guess, number of records shouldn't be issue,for testing purpose, limit your records return (like 10) and see if this works. Check textbox id too. sometimes .net render a different control id e.g. ctrl_00_textbox